# Node equivalent to Flask flashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Python Flask, there's a cool set of functions for [flashing](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/) messages in templates. I'm trying to do the same thing in node.js with Express and Pug, but only found [npm node-twinkle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twinkle) which is 6 years old and 0.0.3 (and not adapted for TypeScript).

Are there any other options for the same functionality? I don't want to do heavy front end coding if possible.

Comment: Just search for what you want on npmjs: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=flash%20message

Comment: For express specific modules (so we don't get results for browser related modules for React/Angular/Vue) - https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=express%20flash%20message